# How to save/reload split windows in vim?

Tags: vim, split

How do I get the same split-settings back if I exited vim with `:qa`?

Comment: You'll have to use vim [sessions](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/starting.html#views-sessions). You could see the first part of my answer [here](http://vi.stackexchange.com/a/4826/1841) for details on the use of sessions.